# generating functions as jet bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, generating-functions

It is well-known that a Taylor series is an exponential generating function.
$$
F = \sum_k a_k\frac{x^k}{k!}
$$
where the coefficients are $k$th order derivatives of $F$.

It is also known that derivatives have a geometrical interpretation as elements of a tangent space above a point. I have been wondering if the coefficients of a generating function can be mapped to a set of $k$th order jet spaces above a point.

Thus, how can we construct the generating function given this picture? The coefficients would be the collection of all spaces above a point, how would the $x^k$ terms look? Some kind of product space?

Can an (ordinary) generating function be described in the language of differential geometry and does this introduce any interesting perspectives?

I have little background in maths.

Comment: I did not understand everything you said, but if I'm not too much minsunderstanding, you should look at the notion of "jet-bundle" on a manifold. See, for example, "partial differential relations" from M. Gromov. But if you have a little background in mathematics, it would look pretty obscur to you...